# Можно ли поменять несколько (умных) указателей через одну из его копий?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointer

Вопрос простой: мне необходимо, что бы я мог, используя один указатель, поменять адреса данных всех его копий (ну, к примеру, **shared_ptr**). Для чего это нужно? Ну, к примеру, есть функция, которая возвращает указатель. Но затем я двигаю память в куче, и хочу, что бы возвращенный мною указатель обладал изменчивостью именно на такой случай и смог остаться валидным после сдвига. Возможно ли такое сделать стандартными средствами, и практикуются ли вообще такие штуки?

Comment: Что значит *"двигаю память в куче"*?

Comment: лично я ничего не понел.  но хотелось бы понять

Comment: Сделайте указатель на указатель и меняйте на здоровье

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, выход простой: хранить указатель на указатель, в моем случае я использовал `std::shared_ptr <std::unique_ptr <Type>>`